# Bootstrap form with one row and two columns: Only one column of form values gets submitted

Tags: node.js, express, bootstrap-4, pug

On form POST, only the first column of form data get submitted. The second column (category and priority) are undefined. If I move the submit button to the second column the exact opposite happens. Then if I rearrange the form to have only one column, all of the form values get submitted(temp work around). How can I implement this form with two columns and have the entire form submitted?

Console log output:

```
from CREATE ISSUE CONTROLLER
req.body.title: New bug report
req.body.description: New bug report
req.body.priority: undefined
req.body.category: undefined
```

The form code (.pug):

```
#newissue.tab-pane.fade(role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="newissue-tab")
  .row
    .col-md-6.offset-md-2.new-issue-form
      form(method="POST" action="/newissue")
        .form-group
          label(for="newIssueTitle") Title
          input#newIssueTitle.form-control(type="text" placeholder="Issue title ..." name='title' required='true')
        .form-group
          label(for="newIssueDescription") Description
          textarea#newIssueDescription.form-control(rows="10" placeholder="description" name='description' required='true')
        div
          input#filepond(type="file" name="filepond" data-max-files="10" multiple="")
          button.btn.btn-success(type="submit") Create New Issue
    .col-md-2.new-issue-form.input-group.mb-3
        .form-group.mb-3
          label(for="category") Category
          select#category.form-control(type='select', placeholder='Category ...' name='category' required='true')
            for category in categories
              option(value=category._id) #{category.name}
        .form-group.mb-3
          label(for="priority") Priority
          select#priority.form-control(type='select', placeholder='Priority ...' name='priority' required='true')
            option(selected="") Priority...
                each pri in priorities_list
                    option(value=pri._id) #{pri.name}
                else
                    li No priorites
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way the Pug is written, none of your second column is inside the `form` element. All elements of a form have to be inside of the `form` element in order to be submitted.

Try moving the `form` element to contain the entire `.row`:

```
#newissue.tab-pane.fade(role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="newissue-tab")
  form(method="POST" action="/newissue")
    .row
      .col-md-6.offset-md-2.new-issue-form
        .form-group
          label(for="newIssueTitle") Title
          input#newIssueTitle.form-control(type="text" placeholder="Issue title ..." name='title' required='true')
        .form-group
          label(for="newIssueDescription") Description
          textarea#newIssueDescription.form-control(rows="10" placeholder="description" name='description' required='true')
        div
          input#filepond(type="file" name="filepond" data-max-files="10" multiple="")
          button.btn.btn-success(type="submit") Create New Issue
      .col-md-2.new-issue-form.input-group.mb-3
        .form-group.mb-3
          label(for="category") Category
          select#category.form-control(type='select', placeholder='Category ...' name='category' required='true')
            for category in categories
              option(value=category._id) #{category.name}
        .form-group.mb-3
          label(for="priority") Priority
          select#priority.form-control(type='select', placeholder='Priority ...' name='priority' required='true')
            option(selected="") Priority...
                each pri in priorities_list
                    option(value=pri._id) #{pri.name}
                else
                    li No priorites
```